# Rails Active Storage REST API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I've been able to set up `Active Storage` file uploads and now I'm trying to return associated images when I do, for instance, `Speaker.all` or `Speaker.find(2)`.

Calling the associated endpoint I get something like:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Rafael",
    "email": "rafael.almeida@mail-provider.com",
    "company": "XING",
    "social_media": "{\"twitter\": \"@rafaelcpalmeida\"}",
    "created_at": "2018-10-01T17:21:50.993Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-10-01T17:21:51.144Z"
}
```

How can I also return its associated avatar?

Comment: Try `Speaker.find(2).avatar` (I’m guessing your models)

Comment: @iGian already did, that doesn't return the avatar with the rest of the JSON I've posted above :(

Comment: I don't think you can join `Speaker` with `ActiveStorage::Attachment` and `ActiveStorage::Blob`, but you can always add elements manually to your data structure. What do you need exactly from associated avatar (filename, metadata, byte_size, ...)? What's the expected output?

Comment: I want to append to the `Speaker` JSON structure the path for his own avatar. I’ve managed to do it using views and iterating over an array of `Speaker`s for instance, however, I can’t seem to be able to do it with the json return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what to do in order to achieve the result I wanted. First, we need to add the `active_model_serializers` to the `Gemfile`, followed by `bundle install`.

After we installed the gem we should add `include ActionController::Serialization` to every controller that's going to use the Serializer.

We generate a new serializer using `rails g serializer speaker`. My `SpeakerSerializer` looks like:

```
class SpeakerSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :email, :company, :avatar

  def avatar
    rails_blob_path(object.avatar, only_path: true) if object.avatar.attached?
  end
end
```

And my output looks like

```
{
    "speaker": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Rafael",
        "email": "rafael.almeida@xing.com",
        "company": "XING",
        "avatar": "/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBCdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--515a0de8817b3529b5d3d168871cebf6ccee0463/xing-photo.jpg"
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work unless you import the url helpers first. Then it works great. Below the SpeakerSerializer class declaration add: include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

Answer (score 0):

Check if this approach is good for your needs. This is the case of `has_one_attached`.

First, fetch the record:

```
speaker = Speaker.find(2)
```

Then convert it to a Ruby hash (please note `.as_json`):

```
speaker_hash = speaker.as_json
```

Now, just append the pair key-value you need, using `url_for` helper:

```
speaker_hash['url'] = url_for(speaker.avatar)
```

Finally, convert the hash to json:

```
speaker_hash.to_json
```